# Multi-Agent framework SACI not found error

Tags: java, jar, agent

I am finding java based multi agent framework SACI since the project I am working get errors

```
import saci.agent.*;
```

Is there any jar file related with saci?

Comment: Is it about SACI environment for Jason? https://www.emse.fr/~boissier/enseignement/maop11/doc/jason-api/api/jason/infra/saci/SaciEnvironment.html

Comment: Yes,it is. I could not find jar file.

Answer (score 2):

[SACI](https://www.emse.fr/~boissier/enseignement/maop11/doc/jason-api/api/jason/infra/saci/SaciEnvironment.html) is not supported by [Jason](http://jason.sourceforge.net/wp/) anymore. It is suggested to move to the currently supported infrastructures like centralised, JADE for distributed agents and CArtAgO for distributed artefacts.

Anyway, if you still need it, you can find SACI jar file in old versions like [Jason 1.3](https://sourceforge.net/projects/jason/files/jason/version%201.3/) (lib/saci.jar). This [article about Jason](http://jason.sourceforge.net/Jason.pdf) also brings some information on how to use SACI.